# problema con extensiones php en nodejs

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs

recien enpeze en el mundo de los websockets, mi proyecto es puro php estoy tratando de integrar nodejs en mi aplicacion por la question de los websockets so tengo algunas dudas, he estado leiendo y practicando y estube desarrollando en pequeño y simple chat todo iva de maravillas elchat me funcionaba muy bien hasta que intente cambiarle la extencion a mi index.html a index.php , me muestra el navegador en blanco con cannot ge/ . si lo cambio a index.html inmediatamente funciona pero si lo cambio a index.php no me lo lee no entiendo por que estuve buscando tutoriales como solucionarlo pero sigo sin resolver el problemita estoy usando XAMPP en mi proyecto ,una mano ayuda para este novato plis!
[image: este es el error que me muestrra el navegadoe]

y este es mi codigo:

//mi sevidor en nodejs

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const connect = require('connect');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//aqui estan los sockets desde otro archivo js para dejar el codigo de el servidor mas limpio
require('./socket')(io);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


 //voy a establecer un puerto si no tomas el 3000
 app.set('port' , process.env.PORT || 3000)


//voy a recivir el puerto
server.listen(app.get('port') ,()=>{

    console.log('conectado con el servidor '+app.get('port'))
})
```

//los sockets

```
  module.exports= function(io){

    io.on('connection',socket=>{
    console.log('usuarios conectados con io');

    //esta es la accion que se recive desde el cliente
socket.on('mensaje-cliente',function (data) {

     console.log(data);
    //aqui el servidor la emite el mensaje a todos los clientes
    io.sockets.emit('mensaje-servidor', data);
})

 })

 }
```

mi index.html //si lo cambio a index.php nada de nada

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>chat websocket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-primary">

   <a href="" class="navbar-brand mx-auto">WebsocketChat</a>

    </nav>
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>lets Chat</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="chat" class="card-body">


            </div>

            <form class="card-footer" action="index.html" method="post" id="message-form">
                <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="text" name="" id="message" class="form-control">
                 <div class="input-group-append">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" id="enviar">
                 </div>

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    //ya intente cambiarlo a http://localhost:3000 pero nada de nada
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

micliente main.js

```
 $(function () {

   var socket=io();
//intente poner esta linea en el cliente pero tampoco
//var sockets = io.connect( 'http://localhost:' );

   //obteniendo los elementos del Dom 

   var formulario = $("#message-form");
   var mensajebox = $("#chat");
   var mensaje = $("#message");
   var enviar = $("#enviar");

    formulario.submit( e =>{

        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(mensaje.val());

   //aquii con socket.io le damos un nombre al evento y capturamos el mensaje y *
        socket.emit('mensaje-cliente',mensaje.val());
        //limpiar input despues de enviar
           mensaje.val("");
    });

  /*aqui nos toca escuchar el mensaje atraves de la palabra clave del servidor*/

    socket.on('mensaje-servidor',function(data){

        //aqui elegimos donde mostrar el mensaje del servidor
        mensajebox.append(data+'<br>');
    });
})
```

Comment: nodejs no sabe como interpretar extensiones php, lo que tienes que investigar es como hacer un reverse proxy para que nodejs se comunique con el procesamiento que hace apache a archivos .php; por que tal cual lo tienes no va a servir

Comment: gracias prestar atencion a mi preguntad @AlfredoPaz me podrias explicar un poquito mas a detalle que es eso de proxy escusame es que recien llevo como 8 meses programando y hay cosas que aun no entiendo

Comment: resolvi el problema ya estoy usando nodejs y y apache en el mismo puerto fue duro el camino pero lo logre puedo usar socket.io de nodejs en mi php el que quiera o esta en lo mismo me puede escrivir por aqui yo los ayudare sin problemas gracias